# ssh/shh-copy-id Works for root but not other users

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, operating-system, admin

I am trying to enable SSH into my Ubuntu server as a non-root user via `ssh-copy-id`. On my local machine `ssh-copy-id root@server` works fine but when I run ssh-copy-id other@server I get a `Permission denied (publickey).` error. The `home/other` directory is completely empty. What do I have to do to utilize an ssh as the other user

Answer (score 0):

On your remote machine create a `./ssh` folder inside of the other users directory. Then inside of this directory create a file called `authorized_keys`. Copy the public key from your local host into this file, you will now be able to ssh into your server via `ssh other@server`